# How can I avoid Windows Service error 1053 in my .NET 5 WebApp during database migration with Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, windows-services

My .NET 5 WebApp runs as a Windows Service and uses Entity Framework to seed and update (migrate) its database during startup. Before calling `Host.Run()`, I make sure that my database is updated. This has worked perfectly fine for the past year. Now, I have a large database update that takes a few minutes to complete. During this database update, the Windows Service will shut down with error 1053, denoting a timeout. I suspect this is due to the runtime not reaching the call for `Host.Run()` in the given default timeout period (about 30 seconds as it seems). The problem is that I have to perform these database updates before calling `Host.Run()`, as the database should be properly updated before any accesses to it are made.

What is the simplest solution to this issue? I could try to write a custom Service Lifetime to increase the timeout. I could move the update of the database to be performed after `Host.Run()` with the additional overhead of restricting accesses while it is performed. I don't like either of these solutions yet and seek a better alternative. Maybe I am wrong in my assumptions altogether as well. My code is provided below.

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
       
        using (IServiceScope scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            IServiceProvider services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            SeedAndUpdateDb seed = services.GetRequiredService<SeedAndUpdateDb>();
            await seed.InitializeAsync(); //<- This call takes a few minutes to complete
        }

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
    
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var hostingConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
            
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                {
                    serverOptions.Configure(hostingConfig.GetSection("Kestrel"));
                });
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                { });
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line is this: if your running executable is to be recognized as a started Windows Service, it must (after installation as a service and being started as such) upon service startup tell the [Windows Service Control Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-control-manager) that it is in fact a service and that it has started successfully.

If it doesn't do so in time, you get the dreaded error message that the service didn't start in time.

Your call to `.UseWindowsService()` sets up all that plumbing to the SCM, but the call to the SCM is only made inside the .NET Core Host startup code in `await host.RunAsync()`.

So if between your executable starting (due to you starting the service) and your code calling `await host.RunAsync()` too much time elapses, your executable will be running and your *hosted service* will eventually run, but as far as Windows is concerned, your *Windows Service* did not start (in time).

The solution is to call the migration using a command-line flag, not on every startup. Or call the migration once inside your hosted service, so when the Windows Service is already running.

For the command-line approach: so after a deployment, you can run `Your-Service.exe --migrate` before starting the Windows Service.

Something like this:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
   
    if (args.Any(a => a == "--migrate"))
    {
        using (IServiceScope scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            IServiceProvider services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            SeedAndUpdateDb seed = services.GetRequiredService<SeedAndUpdateDb>();
            await seed.InitializeAsync(); //<- This call takes a few minutes to complete
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Database migrated, you can now start the service");
    }
    else
    {
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good tip. Didn't know this was possible! However, maybe my question is incomplete? Not only do I perform the migration in that method (which doesn't take long usually), but I also perform an update on the data in the tables (to fill new fields I added with the proper data).

Comment: See edit, so either migrate and seed, or start the service, not both.

Comment: Interesting, I will try this and report back once I have sufficient results!

Comment: I have finally tested this. Providing command line arguments works as expected. Starting the program with the arguments as a service still does not work, as the service reports the usual timeout error. However, starting it on the command-line and waiting for it to terminate does the trick. I would say this is more of a workaround than a direct solution to my problem. I'm still puzzled as to how I can avoid a timeout if I start it as a service with the migration, but since this works for me I'm going to leave the topic alone for now and implement it exactly like this! Thanks!

Comment: @Alpha I have updated my answer with more explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: Your explanation fits to what I expected was happening. Thanks for the clarification! Your solution is exactly what I'm doing now, and it works just fine. To reiterate: I would prefer the migration to run after the service starts but that is simply impossible with the current way the program is set up. So this way, though incurring a slightly higher grade of administration, works best for me. For the other case I would have to change existing structures when it comes to starting up the service and allowing users to access it and I would prefer to not touch that.